# Ruby/Rails parse XML without loading it all into memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xml-parsing

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to parse an XML document in rails without loading it all into ram.
I've been using (depending on the XML) a combination of Nokogiri and the standard Hash.from_xml to pull get the contents of the XML.
That is all well and good when I'm dealing with (attempting to import) 100 or even 1000 products. When however the XML doc has 16,000 or 40,000 products in it....  well my Dino starts to really really feel it.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to walk the XML without pulling it all into memory.

Sorry I don't have code.... I'm attempting to avoid writing anything new.  I mean who wants to write their own XML parser eh?

Answer (score 1):

I came to this...

```
reader = Nokogiri::JSON::Reader(File.open('test.xml'))

reader.each do |node|
  if(node.name == 'Product')
    hash = Hash.from_xml(node.outer_xml).values.first
    break;
  end
end
```

I watched my memory load while I ran this across a 60 meg file. It accomplished my goal.  I'd love to see other answers.  Perhaps something even lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Because XML is hierarchical the parser needs to know the whole structure to parse it correctly. You could feed well formed fragments to `Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse` but you'd need to get those fragments out some other way.

Let's say you have a huge xml document:

```
<products>
  <product>stuff</product>
  <product>...</product>
  ... and so on
</products>
```

The actual products are enveloped within `<products>`, strip out the envelope part and then using string splitting to get an array of each `<product>` and its contents. Then parse each of these as XML fragments. Just a thought.

This might help, although I've never used it: https://github.com/soulcutter/saxerator